# GSRegisterPurpleNamedPerPIDPort crash

Tags: ios, crash-reports

```
Thread 0 Crashed: 0 libsystem_kernel.dylib 0x1be21acc __pthread_kill + 8 
1libsystem_pthread.dylib 0x1beda086 pthread_kill + 62 
2 libsystem_c.dylib 0x1bdb695a abort + 108 
3 GraphicsServices 0x1dd0b83a GSRegisterPurpleNamedPerPIDPort + 0 
4 GraphicsServices 0x1dd0aad8 _GSEventInitializeApp + 106 
5 UIKit 0x21af68e8 _UIApplicationMainPreparations + 832 
6 UIKit 0x218e2de2 UIApplicationMain + 102 
7 LanSynergism 0x000d160e main (main.m:14) 
8 libdyld.dylib 0x1bd4e4ea start
```

---

### crash why  when the app kill and begin

Comment: Can you please add some code? Otherwise it will be very hard to help you out. See also https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: The program is started to collapse, no execution code

Answer (score 0):

I had this happen to me. The cause for me was the Xcode debugger was still attached to the app on an exception breakpoint. So when I tried to relaunch the app it would close instantly with a stacktrace:

```
Thread 0 Crashed:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001adc810cc __pthread_kill + 8
1   libsystem_c.dylib               0x00000001adbda14c abort + 144
2   GraphicsServices                0x00000001b02b99e8 GSRegisterPurpleNamedPerPIDPort + 0
3   GraphicsServices                0x00000001b02b8b24 _GSEventInitializeApp + 132
4   UIKitCore                       0x00000001db515b70 _UIApplicationMainPreparations + 960
5   UIKitCore                       0x00000001db515724 UIApplicationMain + 164
6   MyWorldClock                    0x000000010043c188 main + 688520 (AppDelegate.swift:20)
7   libdyld.dylib                   0x00000001adb34fd8 start + 4
```

This looks to be the same as posted above.

The steps I was taking was I had Xcode debugger attached with exception breakpoints on, I changed the iOS device language which sent kill signal to all the apps, since the debugger was attached it fired the breakpoint. When trying to relaunch the app with debugger paused on the SIGABRT exception the app would open and close instantly on iOS device.

Hope this helps someone!